# Função recursiva retornando undefined no Javascript com Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursão, undefined

A função recursiva abaixo para de executar quando chega no "if (sorted) " e a condição é verdadeira, como deveria fazer. Só que não importa o que eu coloco para retornar, ela não retorna.

Se eu boto return 1, ela retorna undefined por exemplo. 
Não tem lógica isso

OBS: já dei console.log na variável "sorted", ela contém o booleano true.

Sou obrigado a ter um return num else também? Mas dá não funciona nada, porque o sorted na primeira chamada da função, é false, aí ja entra no else e para tudo.

O código está sendo escrito na plataforma Hackerhank. A Main e entradas e saídas já vem configurados.

```
function minimumSwaps(arr, cont) {
    let sorted = arr.every(isAlreadySorted)
    if (sorted) return 1 
......
.....
..
}
```

E lá na função Main:

```
function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

    const arr = readLine().split(' ').map(arrTemp => parseInt(arrTemp, 10));

    var cont = 0
    const res = minimumSwaps(arr, cont);


    ws.write(res + '\n');

    ws.end();
}
```

minimumSwaps retorna undefined. E logo, o res printado na tela é undefined

Comment: Oi Lucas, podes criar um exemplo com o problema que dê para correr aqui? assim como está falta código para identificarmos o problema...

Answer (score 0):

A questão é que aparentemente o Javascript no Node não deixa uma função ter return apenas no if e não no else.

A função funcionou corretamente quando eu coloquei a chama recursiva como *return* do *else* do *if* de retorno:

```
function minimumSwaps(arr, cont) {
....
....
...

    let sorted = arr.every(isAlreadySorted)
    if (sorted) return 1 
    else return minimumSwaps(arr, cont)
```